# Controller Knows About Service Mock, but Unit Test Doesn't (AngularJS, Karma-Jasmine)

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm adding unit tests to my AngularJS application, and running into an issue where the controller I'm testing is aware of my mocks (logs the correct mock object), but my unit tests cannot return the mock value. I've been stuck on this one for a while.

**Mock Service**

```
angular.module('mocks.myService', [])
  .factory('myService', function() {
      var service = {
        hi : 'hi'
      };
      return service;
  });
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['myService', function(myService) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.doThing = function() {
    console.log(myService);
    // Object{hi:'hi'}
  };

}]);
```

**Unit Test**

```
describe('myApp.selection module', function() {
    var myCtrl, myService;

    beforeEach(function() {
      myService = module('mocks.myService');
      console.log(myService);
      // undefined
    });

    describe('controller', function(){
      it('should exist', inject(function($controller) {
         myCtrl = $controller('MyCtrl');
         expect(myCtrl).toBeDefined();
      }));

      it ('should do thing', function() {
         myCtrl.doThing();
      });

   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
describe('myApp.selection module', function () {
 var myCtrl, myService;

 beforeEach(module("mocks.myService"));

 beforeEach(inject(function (_myService_) {
     myService = _myService_;
     console.log(myService);
 }));

 describe('controller', function () {
     it('should exist', inject(function ($controller) {
         myCtrl = $controller('MyCtrl');
         expect(myCtrl).toBeDefined();
     }));

     it('should do thing', function () {
         myCtrl.doThing();
     });

 });

});
```

source: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing